# Play-Scala add commas and decimal point to Double datatype

Tags: scala, playframework

I have this problem starting from getting data from DB to present it to the user.. I have overcame some issues, but I don't think it's a best practice.. Here is my problem:

In my DB, I have a field with type `double(15,2)`, I want to show it to the user in this format `xxx,xxx,xxx.yy`. Currently if I just show what I got from the DB, it's in something like this format `99e10`.. Is there any best practice to achieve what I want ?

NOTE: I'm currently formatting the value from Javascript which gives some glitches when I continuously refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java DecimalFormat class to pretty your output

Refer : [Decimal Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Try it in REPL and check it fit your expectations:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat
val d = 9182379812921.12
val f = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00")
f.format(d)
> 9,182,379,812,921.12
```

Comment: It seems correct, but it round up the decimal points if they are zero's.. I still want it to show up, like `9,182,379,812,921.00`..

Comment: Well, I found the solution.. Your current answer will round the decimal point if it's something like 123.00. So the better way is to use `val f = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00")`. If you edit your answer to then I'll give you the right answer.. Thanks though..