# Play-Scala format date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd MMM YYYY

Tags: scala, playframework

I have this date format from database `2014-08-01` and passing it to the controller I have that date with type java.util.Date.. My goal is to get this format: `01 Aug 2014`

This is what I have done so far:

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
format.format(new java.util.Date())
play.api.Logger.info(format.parse(ls.si_due_date.toString).toString)
```

Comment: Same as for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305197/play-scala-add-commas-and-decimal-point-to-double-datatype (quite a duplicate question): https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaCustomTemplateFormat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the solution

```
val incommingDate = "2014-08-01"
val formatIncomming = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val formatOutgoing = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy")    
val dateFormated = formatOutgoing.format(formatIncomming.parse(incommingDate))
println(dateFormated)
```

Comment: One question though, currently I want to put it in a `case class` which has `si_due_date: Date`, however it shows this error `found : String required: java.util.Date`.. Is there a way to convert the output from `.format` into `java.util.Date` ?

Answer (score -1):

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

String date= "8-Aug-2014";

```
try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```